# How to declare a node.js variable that i can later use in my js file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, variables, node-modules

So I have set up a node.js file that i'm calling "app.js". It looks like this:

```
const fs = require('fs')
var myInfo = fs.readFileSync('info.txt', 'utf8')
```

I have stored the content of 'info.txt' in the variable "myInfo". I want to display that content in an html page that is named "index.html". I wonder if there is any way I could get access to the variable "myInfo" from my javascript file, that I call "script.js" (which is linked to the html of course).

All of these files: "index.html","script.js","app.js","info.txt"

are stored in the same folder, which I call "node-test"

Comment: Are you using NWJS?

Answer (score 3):

A program running in a `<script>` element on a webpage and a program running under Node.js are **two different programs** even if they are written using the same programming language.

They cannot directly share data.

Typical approaches to this problem would involve writing a webserver using Node.js and either:

- Replacing `index.html` with a template so when you request `/` from that webserver, it gets populated with the data.
- Providing a web service that the JavaScript in the webpage interacts with by making an HTTP request (typically with the `fetch` API).

Either way, it would be useful to take a look at the Express module for Node.js.